# Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I encountered this issue when retrieving a token from AWS cognito by using username,password and clientId.

Issue is

> "Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.NotAuthorizedException:
> Incorrect username or password.".

I retrieve the token from AWS cognito using ASP.net core